# admin.common.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

working on nopcommerce plugin development using Kendo grid UI. but facing this problem in view side Kendo grid not populated with data. therer is  error on console   `

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) 
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) 
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function)
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) 
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function)
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) 
>   Uncaught Error: AdminLTE requires jQuery(anonymous function)
>   Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function) 
>   Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoDatePicker is not a function`

I'm using like this

```
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/admin.search.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/scripts/admin.navigation.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/admin.common.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/adminLTE/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using several scripts, they have to follow an specific order, because they are triggered from the first one to the last. So for example if you call a JQuery function in "admin.common.js" and you haven't called JQuery then it will throw you that error. Also bootstrap needs JQuery, so JQuery should be placed before bootstrap, and so on. So you might try this instead:

```
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js">  </script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/admin.search.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/scripts/admin.navigation.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/admin.common.js"></script>
<script src="~/Administration/Scripts/adminLTE/app.min.js"></script>
```

If the above doesn't work, try and reorganize your scripts so that they all require the one before.

Hope this helps, 
Leo.